# how to design a job scheduler for many kinds of job?

Tags: architecture, cluster-computing, instance, microservices

I am junior developer and wanted to ask a question on design/architecture of a job scheduler.

I am designing the architecture for a scheduler that manages multiples tasks.
There are multiple categories(over 70) eg movie, shopping, food.
Each category has three or more tasks that need to be implemented.
So my scheduler needs to execute tasks for each category when needed.
Tasks for each category are independent of one another. 
So, tasks for categoryA can run in parallel with those of categoryB depending on the schedule.

So, I have two types of design that I have in mind to do this. 
One is turning each category as a separate service, to run on individual instance. This way, it's modular but the system will consume too many instances(over 70) even when there is no task running for each category.

category1

- task1
- task2
- task3

...

category2

- task1
- task2
- task3

...

category3

- task1
- task2
- task3

...

The other idea I have is to group categories by each task. So, each task becomes a module itself and inside each task, there is a collection of specific tasks that belong to different categories.

task1

- task1 related to category1
- task1 related to category2
- task1 related to category3

...

task2

- task2 related to category1
- task2 related to category2
- task2 related to category3

...

task3

- task3 related to category1
- task3 related to category2
- task3 related to category3

Which one is do you think is a better design? I'd love your insight into this. Thank you :)

Comment: Honestly, job scheduling and management is a wide topic, so unless this is a fun project, I would use one of the services/solutions available in the market, both open source (like http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) and commercial (like http://infinitedata.com/products/schedulein)

Answer (score 2):

Scheduling a job must have these basic functionalities

1. Scheduling Job
2. Unscheduling/Deleting scheduled job
3. Processing based on priority (Will be useful in long-term), Maybe you 
    can prioritize based on the categories you have. Explore redis here as it has amazing capabilities to save ordered set

I would suggest keeping the job queueing service and job processing service (i.e workers) different as this will enable your application to work as an black box